# SMTP client not translating inline HTML

Tags: c#, .net, smtpclient

i'm having issues sending inline HTML into an email using the SMTP/.NET mail.  I've tried the standard class, as well as the MailDefininition class, but i keep getting inline the raw code, not the translated page.

I know it is probably something small that i am missing, below is my code. Thanks

```
     public static void SendMail(string toAddress,  string subject, string messageBody)
    {
        MailDefinition message = new MailDefinition();
        message.CC = MailCCAddress;
        message.From = "orders@test.com";
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        ListDictionary replacements = new ListDictionary();

        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage fileMsg;
        fileMsg = message.CreateMailMessage(toAddress, replacements, messageBody, new System.Web.UI.Control());

        string _hostName = HostName;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(_hostName);
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        //client.Send(message);
        client.Send(fileMsg);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also wish to set the `MailMessage` Body-Encoding if you are still having trouble. For example,

```
//Nick's code
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("orders@test.com", toAddress, subject, messageBody);
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

//set encoding
mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; //or SevenBit, etc, whatever is appropriate.

//send
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(_hostName);
client.Send(mail);
```

You can also use the AlternateViews collection which gives you better control of the MIME type of the content (so you can specify it as text/html, etc). You can also use this to optionally include *both* a plain text version and an HTMLversion, like this:

```
//create the mail message
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("orders@test.com", toAddress) { Subject = subject };

//first we create the Plain Text part
AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("This is my plain text content, viewable by those clients that don't support html", null, "text/plain");
//then we create the Html part
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<b>this is bold text, and viewable by those mail clients that support html</b>", null, "text/html");

//add both views
mail.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

//send the message as before
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("orders@test.com", toAddress, 
    subject, messageBody);

mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(_hostName);
client.Send(mail);
```

If this doesn't work then it could be a problem with your messageBody.  You can try debugging the code and see if there is a problem with messageBody not being proper html or it could have some characters escaped.